# python: remove duplicate elements based on score

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following list

```
l = [ {'id':1, 's':1.0 }, {'id':3, 's': 0.6}, {'id':1, 's': 1.5} ]
```

I would like to remove elements with duplicate `'id'` value, based on their `'s'` value.
In the former example, I would like to discard the first element since both the first and third elements has `'id'==1` and since `l[0]['s'] < l[2]['s']` I would like `l[0]` to be discarded.

Therefore the output I expect is (I do **not** care about the order of the elements in the output list)

```
[ {'id':1, 's':1.5}, {'id':3, 's':0.6} ]
```

Comment: How much does ordering matter? Are there any other keys in the input dictionaries or are there only `id` and `s` keys?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do not care for the ordering of the output list.

Comment: Where did this list come from?

Comment: @Aya - the list is a result of all sorts of processing. I have little control over its creation.

Comment: @Shai Okay. Just checking it wasn't possible to omit those in the first place.

Comment: @Aya - no, I tries that - lot of mess...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a mapping to track ids and their scores:

```
from collections import defaultdict

id_to_scores = defaultdict(list)

for entry in l:
    id_to_scores[entry['id']].append(entry['s'])

output = [{'id': k, 's': max(v)} for k, v in id_to_scores.iteritems()]
```

Use `.items()` instead if you are using Python 3.

Result (ordering changed because a `dict` has no fixed ordering):

```
>>> [{'id': k, 's': max(v)} for k, v in id_to_scores.iteritems()]
[{'s': 1.5, 'id': 1}, {'s': 0.6, 'id': 3}]
```

This rebuilds the dictionaries. If there are other keys involved, you need to store the whole dictionary for each `id`, not just the score:

```
per_id = defaultdict(list)

for entry in l:
    per_id[entry['id']].append(entry)

output = [max(v, key=lambda d: d['s']) for v in per_id.itervalues()]
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I was kind of hoping for a solution that does not require the "re-generation" of `l`, since in my case there are many fields to each element and not only `'id'` and `'s'`...

Answer (score 4):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
In [58]: dic=defaultdict(dict)

In [59]: for x in lis:
    idx=x['id']
    if dic[idx].get('s',float('-inf')) < x ['s']:
        dic[idx]=x
   ....:         

In [60]: dic.values()
Out[60]: [{'id': 1, 's': 1.5}, {'id': 3, 's': 0.6}]
```

Using simple `dict` :

```
In [71]: dic={}

In [72]: for x in lis:
    idx=x['id']
    if dic.get(idx, {'s': float('-inf')}) ['s'] < x['s']:
        dic[idx]=x
   ....:         

In [73]: dic.values()
Out[73]: [{'id': 1, 's': 1.5}, {'id': 3, 's': 0.6}]
```

Comment: @jamylak - I'm not sure this solution works (or have I missed something here?). `dic` has no key `'s'` at any stage, so `dic.get('s',float('-inf'))` will always be `-inf`...

Comment: @Shai not my solution but that must be a typo, should be `idx`

Comment: I often see answers with `In`/`Out` and line number prefixes. Where does this come from (IDE or some other tool)?

Comment: There is no point here in using `defaultdict` since you are replacing the default mapping wholesale. May as well use `dic.get(idx, {'s': float('-inf')}) < x['s']` and drop the `defaultdict` altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution, using groupby from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

```
>>> l = [ {'id':1, 's':1.0 }, {'id':3, 's': 0.6}, {'id':1, 's': 1.5} ]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> key = lambda dct: dct['id']
>>> l.sort(key=key)
>>> for key, group in groupby(l, key=key):
...     print max(group, key=lambda dct: dct['s'])
... 
{'s': 1.5, 'id': 1}
{'s': 0.6, 'id': 3}
```

**Re: Ashwini**

I've done a [performance test](http://pastebin.com/aBDYc0GV), comparing the different solutions. Here's the results, in graph form:

[image]

I've used only 10 different values for the `'id'` key here, you may play with the code yourself to see how the composition of `lst` affects the results. Changing the number of `id` values to half the number of items in the list makes Ashwini the clear victor, and puts the rest of us in a lump:

[image]

This is how it looks when you compare an `O(n)` solution with an `O(n*log(n))` solution in a log-log graph:

[image]

So, I'm not quite sure what conclusion to draw with regards to the big O argument.

Comment: Sorting makes it `O(NLogN)` solution, but this can be done in `O(N)`.

Comment: @Ashwini Are you sure? With the defaultdict solution, you have to create a list for each id and go through that list at the end to find the max. Isn't that just a O(NLogN) solution in disguise?

Comment: I am looping through the `list` only once and updating `dic` based on the conditions, and then `dic.values()` is also a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [ {'id':1, 's':1.0 }, {'id':3, 's': 0.6}, {'id':1, 's': 1.5} ]
>>> res = {}
>>> for d in L:
        id_ = d['id']
        res[id_] = max(res.get(id_, {}), d, key=lambda x: x.get('s', float('-inf')))


>>> res.values()
[{'s': 1.5, 'id': 1}, {'s': 0.6, 'id': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l2={}
>>> for y in l:
        l2.setdefault(y['id'],[]).append(y['s'])
>>> l3=[{'id':k,'s':max(v)} for k,v in l2.items()]
>>> print l3
```

gives:

```
[{'id': 1, 's': 1.5}, {'id': 3, 's': 0.6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort by descending `s`, so that for each `id`, the highest `s` comes first. Then only pick the first occurrence of an `id`.

```
seen = set()
output = [d for d in sorted(l, key=lambda d: d['s'], reverse=True)
          if d['id'] not in seen and not seen.add(d['id'])]
```

You might as well decide to first sort in place, to avoid additional space at the cost of touching the input.

All of this may not be optimal in terms of time and space complexity, but it's quite elegant.